# How to run asynchronous tasks for multiple users

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

So I've this project for school who is about "triggers" for social networks.

Let me explain: 
- A user can register for our application and login
- He can sign in for multiple services like Facebook, Twitter etc.
- Then their is what we call triggers, once he signed in on our application and registered his services, everytime he will post something on twitter for example my server will see it and post it on Facebook aswell.

I knew nothing about node.js a month ago so I'm kinda new to all this async stuff but I took some course to help myself. So far so good I can now manage users etc, (I've again some research to do with oauth).

My biggest problem is this "real-time" update on our server.
I mean I searched on the internet and saw this what we call polling (?), the idea to make request frequently to a server every X seconds.

So with a bit a sudo code this what I tought it would look like:

```
For each User
   asynchronously watch for every update on Facebook and Twitter for 
   this User
```

So I did some research about performing request every each second and found about setInterval and setTimeout

```
const watchSocialMedia = setInterval(function(){
  Users.forEach(user => {
        User.watchAndPostAnyNewPost() //
   } 
}, 60000);
```

So I put some dummy data to illustrate. 
Problem is I don't think It'll be done asynchronously ?

I mean the ideal is if I could put one time for each user a 'watcher' like saying

```
For each User
  User.watchAndPostAnyNewPost()
```

where watchAndPostAnyNewPost() look like this

```
class User () {
 ...

 const watchAndPostAnyNewPost = setInterval(function(){
     fetchFacebook();
     fetchTwitter();
  }, 60000);
}
```

So each user have his own setInterval function running on him to check if he posted anything

Anyone can tell me if it's even possible ? :-)

Thanks a lot for reading me !!!

Comment: That will not scale at all. After a couple 1000 people sign up, you'll run out of timers you can hook to the scheduler, and your server will crash.

Comment: setInterval and setTimeout are asynchronous however they are part of the Browser's Object Model (the `window` object to be exact) and don't exist on Node. For node, check out [timers](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) which are also asynchronous.

Comment: @ScottMarcus have you even looked at that link you just shared? `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` are both defined on the global namespace. Yes, they exist in Node, the only difference being the return value is a `Timeout` instead of a positive integer.

Comment: are you using the twitter api, if so you can subscripe to webhooks that will push notifications to your server so you dont have to poll. Same goes for facebooks graph api. ive never looked to far into it, you may have to pay dependent on how many user accounts you are listening too.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts This is what I saw, which very much leads one to believe that the `window` timers are not implemented in node. *The timer functions within Node.js implement a similar API as the timers API provided by Web Browsers but use a different internal implementation that is built around the Node.js Event Loop.* I didn't see that they have the same method names.

Comment: Thanks everybody !! @Tik: I took a look at webhooks for Facebook & twitter but unfortunately I'll have to work with some other API (like Imgur) who don't implement this kind of "real-time" notifications :/

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is totally what scares me. It seems very resource consumption to do it like so. Maybe setInterval will be the first way to go, but my question is if I do my last solution: put a watcher (so a setInterval typically) to each User, they will run asynchronously until I tell them to stop ?